# How to achieve Google's Android 12 app widgets backgrounds?

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-appwidget, android-12

Android 12 came with the new app widget feature *"device theming"* using the system's default theme `@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.DayNight`.

Seeing a screenshot like the one below in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/enhance#dynamic-colors) I was expecting to see more of the theme colours to be picked up in my own widget:

[image: App widget from Android documentation]

Compared to both the screenshot above and Google's app widgets like the ones for the weather and Gmail I can hardly measure any colours being picked up.

I also tried out Material Design 3's way of doing it via `Theme.Material3.DynamicColors.DayNight` with the same result. The screenshot below shows [the Material design example app widget](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/AppWidget) vs Google's weather widget - running on an Android 12 Pixel 5 device.

[image: Material Design 3 vs Google]

**What is that Google's app widgets do differently to pick up so much more colour from the device theme?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got word about the [`system_accent1_*` colours](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color#system_accent1_0) and the blog post https://medium.com/@xch3dx/using-material-you-in-your-app-15ec982eecb4 .

Using `<item name="android:backgroundTint">@android:color/system_accent1_50</item>` I finally got the same background colour as Google has for their widgets.

[image: Still raining in Bergen, but at least the background colour is the same]

Comment: Is there an equivalent which can be used within darkmode also? Because if I set the system accent color (@android:color/system_accent1_50) as background it is only matchting the google widget's background using light mode. 
Testing it in dark mode the background color stays completely unchanged. It seems that this color reference (system_accent1_50) is tied to the theme?
Is there any ?attr/xxxx attribute which does match the background colors of the google widgets?